# AWS SageMaker - Deploy TF Hub Model - "no SavedModel bundles found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, model, amazon-sagemaker

**Context**

I contact you because I try to deploy a TFHub model on SageMaker, but I encounter issues.

**Resources**

The model I desire to deploy is https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/5 (TF2.0 Saved Model (v5)).
I integrate the solution in net6.0 with the following NuGet in their last versions as of 08/11/2022: AWSSDK.S3, AWSSDK.SageMaker and AWSSDK.SageMakerRuntime

**Steps**

1. Deploy Model

   - Model Name: Inception-V3-Trained-on-ImageNet-ILSVRC-2012-CLS
   - Image: 763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:2.10.0-gpu
   - Model Data URL: s3://my-bucket/models/inception_v3_feature_vector/5/imagenet_inception_v3_feature_vector_5.tar.gz
   - Status: **Success**
2. Create Endpoint Config

   - Endpoint Config Name: Extract-Features-Endpoint-Config
   - Instance Type: MlM4Xlarge
   - Initial Instance Count: 1
   - Variant Name: TFS
   - Status: **Success**
3. Create Endpoint

   - Endpoint Name: 30-Endpoint
   - Endpoint Config Name: Extract-Features-Endpoint-Config
   - Status: **Failed**

**Logs**

- The Endpoint Status stays "Creating" for some time, then finally becomes "Failed".
- Via CloudWatch, I observe the following logs:

```
2022-11-08T07:40:10.367+01:00   INFO:__main__:PYTHON SERVICE: False
2022-11-08T07:40:10.367+01:00   INFO:__main__:starting services
2022-11-08T07:40:10.367+01:00   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 502, in <module> ServiceManager().start() File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 482, in start self._create_tfs_config() File "/sagemaker/serve.py", line 153, in _create_tfs_config raise ValueError("**no SavedModel bundles found!**")
2022-11-08T07:40:10.367+01:00   ValueError: **no SavedModel bundles found!**
```

Could you please help me?

In advance thank you for your help!

**What I found so far**

- I checked multiple sources ([ValueError: no SavedModel bundles found! when trying to deploy a TF2.0 model to SageMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882941/valueerror-no-savedmodel-bundles-found-when-trying-to-deploy-a-tf2-0-model-to) and https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1484 among others), and they point out the problem being an invalid .tar.gz architecture with missing number, which is does not seem to be a problem via the archive recovered from tfhub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed an wrong .tar.gz architecture
The model.tar.gz recovered from tfhub is

- model.tar.gz -> 5.tar -> variables dir and saved_model.pb

While SageMaker is waiting for

- model.tar.gz -> 5.tar -> **5** -> variables dir and saved_model.pb

A simple re-packaging saved the day